# Problems Unit Testing with Simpletest 

Tags: php, simpletest, unit-testing

I am using PHP and `simpletest` for unit testing. My tests work fine until I try and set the cookie

```
try{
    setcookie($name,$cookie,$cookie_expires );
}catch Exception($e){
  blah
}
```

The exception is thrown because `simpletest` has already written out header information so I get the following:

> Unexpected PHP error [Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /tests/simpletest/reporter.php:43)] severity [E_WARNING] in [blah_code.php line 280]

I've seen vague explanations on catching this with `$this->expectException(new Exception());` but no further documentation or examples that work. Could someone provide a working example or point me to documentation? To be clear. This is NOT my code producing the output but rather SimpleTest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to get around this is by using output buffering.

You can turn it on globally in PHP's configuration (and possibly in .htaccess), or you can use [ob_start()](http://php.net/ob_start) and its related functions (`ob_get_clean()`, `ob_end_flush()`, etc). For example:

```
ob_start();
// your SimpleTest here.
// your header/ cookie manipulation here.
```

And then:

```
ob_end_clean(); // Stop buffering and dump everything (don't echo).
ob_end_flush(); // Stop buffering and echo out the buffer.
ob_get_clean(); // Stop buffering and return everything as a string.
```

Or any of the other related functions. I believe PHP calls `ob_flush()` at the end of a file if you don't.

Comment: Similar problem here... just adding ob_start() at the very beginning of the file doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

You get this error when you have output before ([header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) functions) `setcookie($name,$cookie,$cookie_expires );`.

Make sure you don't have any  `echos` or `html` or `text` or anything(**NOT EVEN A SPACE**) before `<?php` of `setcookie($name,$cookie,$cookie_expires );`.

Comment: It is Simple test that it creating the output not my code. That is why I posed this question here.

Comment: @Jim I am sorry i seriously misunderstood your question.

Comment: @Jim i think you have use this `simpletest` before outputting anything.